# Getting multiple values in a Flutter DropdownButtonFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter so forgive me if the question sounds silly.
I am developing a Flutter application that has a DropdownButtonFormField.

```
  String _selectedCity;
  String _selectedCountry;

DropdownButtonFormField(
  value: _selectedCity,
  hint: Container(
    child: Text(
      "Select City",
    ),
  ),
  onChanged: (val) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedCity = val;
      _selectedCountry = val;
      //what i would like is : _selectedCountry = name
    });
    print(_selectedCity);
  },
  items: city.map((city) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      value: city.cityId,
      child: Text(city.country),
    );
  }).toList(),
);
```

As it is, I can get the city ID from the dropdown. The issue is, I would like to get the city ID and the city Country and store the country in _selectedCountry.

I have tried adding a second parameter to the onchanged but i get an error.

```
onChanged: (val, country)
```

I don't know what to try and the Flutter documentation doesnt give much information on how to do this.

I will really appreciate any approach suggestions I can get.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the `onChanged` method cannot give your more than one value, but that value doesn't have to be a String!

Lets say you have a class called Region like this:

```
class Region {
  final String country;
  final String city;

  Region(this.country, this.city);
}
```

then instead of using String which is default in DropdownButtonFormField you can define it with the Region class. Now the onChange method returns a Region as well and you have access to the all the data in it. so your code would look like this:

```
  Region _selectedRegion;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DropdownButtonFormField<Region>(
      value: _selectedRegion,
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedRegion = val;
        });
      },

      items: {your data}.map((regionData) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<Region>(
          value: Region(regionData.country, regionData.city),
          child: Text(regionData.city),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ));
  }
```